# CodeIgniter pagination. Total rows

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have this problem and i can't find what is wrong.
So, my Controller:

```
$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "products/page/";
$config["total_rows"] = count($this->model_add->countProducts());
$config["per_page"] = 12;
$config["uri_segment"] = 4;
$config["num_links"] = 2;
$config["use_page_numbers"] = true;
```

model:

```
public function countProducts() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `tdt_articles` WHERE `deleted` = 0 AND `article_type` = 3");
    return $query->result();
}
```

My problem is that in my webpage, it shows less pages that it should show. If on `$config["total_rows"]` i put exact number of records it shows well, but if i count them like is showed there, it doesn't show me all of them. Can't understand at all what is the problem. Hope you'll help me! Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you checked the return of `count($this->model_add->countProducts())` by itself to make sure the result is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're returning an object of data rather than the actual int number of rows. Change your model method to this:

```
public function countProducts() 
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `tdt_articles` WHERE `deleted` = 0 AND `article_type` = 3");
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Alternatively, you can build your querying using active record:

```
public function countProducts()
{
    $result = $this->db->from('tdt_articles')
                       ->where('deleted', 0)
                       ->where('article_type', 3)
                       ->get();

    return $result->num_rows();
}
```

You need to use the `num_rows()` method to get the number of records in a result.

- `result_array()` returns a multidimensional array of results.
- `row_array()` returns a single-dimensional array of results - for one record
- `results()` returns a `stdClass` object
- `num_rows()` returns an integer, which specifies the number of records returned by the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function countProducts() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `tdt_articles` WHERE `deleted` = 0 AND `article_type` = 3");
    return $query->result();
}
```

Shouldn't the select clause read:

```
SELECT count(id) as record_count
```

The method/function should return the output of record_count.

[edit]
Now you don't need to do a count(...) afterward. Plus you let the DB handle it, which is faster than letting php handle it.
[/edit]

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
$total_rows = $this->model_add->countresults()->num_rows();

$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "products/page/";
$config["total_rows"] = $total_rows;
$config["per_page"] = 12;
$config["uri_segment"] = 4;
$config["num_links"] = 2;
$config["use_page_numbers"] = true;
```

model:

```
function countresults() {

      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from($this->table);

      return $this->db->get();

    }
```